# document.getElementById("") = "" does not work in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am looking for a way to set "value" in form, I tried this, but it does not work.
How should I fix it?

The error says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setData is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick

But setDate()  definitely exists....

```
<script>
    function setData() {
        document.getElementById("year").value = "2022";
    }
</script>

<div>
    <form method="GET" action={{ route('test')}}>
        {{ Form::select('month', $date, 0 ) }}
        <input type="button" id="b1" value="BUTTON1" onclick="setData()">
    </form>
</div>

<form method="post" action={{ route('output')}}>
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text"　id="year" name="year" value ="2021"> 
        <input type="text" name="month" value ="7"> <input type="text" name="day" value ="1"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I put the script below the html but another error happened.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.... Actually  I tried to put it "2022"   not null!

Comment: I'm voting to close this because the problem is caused by a typo. The input doesn't have an `id` attribute. It has an attribute where the second and third letters are `id` but the first is `U+3000 : IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` because that was used instead of `U+0020 : SPACE` between attributes. This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below script,

add name to your second form

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('test')}}">
      <select name="" id="month">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="jan">Jan</option>
          <option value="feb">Feb</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" id="b1" value="BUTTON1" onclick="setData()">
</form>

<form method="post" id="form2" action="{{ route('output')}}">
     @csrf
     <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text"　id="year" name="year" value ="2021">
          <input type="text" name="month" value ="7"> <input type="text" name="day" value ="1">
     </div>
</form>

<script>
     var secondForm = document.getElementById('form2');
     
     function setData() {
         secondForm.year.value = '2022';
     }
</script>
```